# Working with shiny's selectizeInput and updateSelectizeInput inside renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, selectize.js, renderui

My basic `shiny` `app` example has a `data.frame` of 20,000 genes, each with an effect and p.value numerical values:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(gene = paste0("g",1:20000), effect = rnorm(20000), p.value = runif(20000,1,0), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And my `app` has two output options to display:

1. A volcano plot, which is a scatter plot of `-log10(df$p.value)` vs. `df$effect`
2. The same as option 1, but allowing the user to select multiple genes to be highlighted in red in the volcano plot

And I'd like the list of genes (to select from) only to appear if option 1 was selected by the user.

Having a `renderUI` within in the `server` where in the `selectInput` the `choices` argument has all 20,000 genes is too slow, so I followed [this tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html) using `selectizeInput` and `updateSelectizeInput`.

Below is my `app` code, where I'm defining the `selectizeInput` within the ui and the `updateSelectizeInput` within the `server`.

It doesn't do what I want:

1. If the `label` variable isn't defined in `selectizeInput` it throws the error: `Error in dots_list(...) : argument "label" is missing, with no default`. But if I do define it, that box appears by default rather than conditioned on the user selecting option 2.
2. The list that appears does not allow selecting from it.
3. My app doesn't display the rendered plot.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(shiny))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(shinyjs))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(DT))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(readr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(plotly))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rmarkdown))

volcanoPlot <- function(df,selected.gene.set=NULL)
{
  plot.df <- df %>%  dplyr::mutate(log10.p.value = -log10(p.value))
  plot.df <- cbind(plot.df,purrr::imap(plot.df, ~ paste(.y, .x, sep=": ")) %>%
                     dplyr::as_tibble() %>%
                     tidyr::unite(text, sep="\n"))
  if(!is.null(selected.gene.set)){
    plot.df$group <- "unselected"
    plot.df$group[which(plot.df$gene %in% selected.gene.set)] <- "selected"
    plot.df$group <- factor(plot.df$group,levels=c("unselected","selected"))
    volcano.plot <- plotly::plot_ly(type='scatter',mode="markers",marker=list(size=5),color=plot.df$group,colors=c("lightgray","darkred"),x=plot.df$effect,y=plot.df$log10.p.value,text=plot.df$text,hoverinfo="text",showlegend=F) %>%
      plotly::layout(xaxis=list(title="Effect",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="-log10(P-value)",zeroline=F))
  } else{
    volcano.plot <- plotly::plot_ly(type='scatter',mode="markers",marker=list(size=5,color="gray"),x=plot.df$effect,y=plot.df$log10.p.value,text=plot.df$text,hoverinfo="text",showlegend=F) %>%
      plotly::layout(xaxis=list(title="Effect",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="-log10(P-value)",zeroline=F))
  }
  return(volcano.plot)
}

output.choices <- c("","Volcano Plot","Highlighted Gene Set Volcano Plot")
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(gene = paste0("g",1:20000), effect = rnorm(20000), p.value = runif(20000,0,1), stringsAsFactors = F)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  output$selected.gene.set <- renderUI({
    req(input$outputType == "Highlighted Gene Set Volcano Plot")
    updateSelectizeInput(session,"selected.gene.set","Select Genes to Highlight",choices=unique(df$gene),multiple=T)
  })

  volcano.plot <- reactive({
    req(input$outputType)
    if(input$outputType == "Volcano Plot"){
      volcano.plot <- volcanoPlot(df=df)
    } else{
      req(input$selected.gene.set)
      volcano.plot <- volcanoPlot(df=df,selected.gene.set=input$selected.gene.set)
    }
    return(volcano.plot)
  })

  output$out.plotly <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    volcano.plot()$volcano.plot
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML(".multicol {-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */column-count: 3;}")),
        tags$style(type="text/css", "#loadmessage {position: fixed;top: 0px;left: 0px;width: 100%;padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 100%;color: #000000;background-color: #CCFF66;z-index: 105;}"),
        tags$style(type="text/css",".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }")),
      conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",tags$div("In Progress...",id="loadmessage")),
      selectInput("outputType", "Output Type", choices = output.choices),
      selectizeInput(inputId='selected.gene.set',label="Select Genes to Highlight",choices=NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotly::plotlyOutput("out.plotly")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is the code for the app available? It is not in the post.

Comment: Yes, forgot to add it before pressing post, sorry about. Just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(gene = paste0("g",1:20000), effect = rnorm(20000), p.value = runif(20000,0,1), stringsAsFactors = F)


suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(shiny))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(shinyjs))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(DT))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(readr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(plotly))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rmarkdown))

volcanoPlot <- function(plot.df,selected.gene.set=NULL)
{
  plot.df <- plot.df %>%  dplyr::mutate(log10.p.value = -log10(p.value))
  plot.df <- cbind(plot.df,purrr::imap(plot.df, ~ paste(.y, .x, sep=": ")) %>%
                     dplyr::as_tibble() %>%
                     tidyr::unite(text, sep="\n"))
  if(!is.null(selected.gene.set)){
    plot.df$group <- "unselected"
    plot.df$group[which(plot.df$gene %in% selected.gene.set)] <- "selected"
    plot.df$group <- factor(plot.df$group,levels=c("unselected","selected"))
    volcano.plot <- plotly::plot_ly(type='scatter',mode="markers",marker=list(size=5),color=plot.df$group,colors=c("lightgray","darkred"),x=plot.df$effect,y=plot.df$log10.p.value,text=plot.df$text,hoverinfo="text",showlegend=F) %>%
      plotly::layout(xaxis=list(title="Effect",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="-log10(P-value)",zeroline=F))
  } else{
    volcano.plot <- plotly::plot_ly(type='scatter',mode="markers",marker=list(size=5,color="gray"),x=plot.df$effect,y=plot.df$log10.p.value,text=plot.df$text,hoverinfo="text",showlegend=F) %>%
      plotly::layout(xaxis=list(title="Effect",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="-log10(P-value)",zeroline=F))
  }
  return(volcano.plot)
}

output.choices <- c("","Volcano Plot","Highlighted Gene Set Volcano Plot")

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  observeEvent(input$outputType,{
    if(req(input$outputType == "Highlighted Gene Set Volcano Plot"))
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"selected.gene.set","Select Genes to Highlight",choices=unique(df$gene),server=T)
  })
  
  volcano.plot <- reactive({
    req(input$outputType)
    if(input$outputType == "Volcano Plot"){
      v.plot <- volcanoPlot(plot.df=df)
    } else{
      req(input$selected.gene.set)
      v.plot <- volcanoPlot(plot.df=df,selected.gene.set=input$selected.gene.set)
    }
    return(v.plot)
  })

  output$out.plotly <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    volcano.plot()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML(".multicol {-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */column-count: 3;}")),
        tags$style(type="text/css", "#loadmessage {position: fixed;top: 0px;left: 0px;width: 100%;padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 100%;color: #000000;background-color: #CCFF66;z-index: 105;}"),
        tags$style(type="text/css",".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }")),
      conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",tags$div("In Progress...",id="loadmessage")),
      selectInput("outputType", "Output Type", choices = output.choices),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.outputType=='Highlighted Gene Set Volcano Plot'",selectizeInput(inputId="selected.gene.set",label=NULL,multiple=T,choices=NULL))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotly::plotlyOutput("out.plotly")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It's important to mention that the reason why your answer provides a solution. Is it that the `updateSelectizeInput` call wasn't working in the server because you didn't send the `server = TRUE` argument?